# What's the best tag to accompany the site-recommendation tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

When asking a 'site recommendation' question, what tag should accompany it? Is there a rule, or general advice, or do we have to improvise in each case?

When you only put the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag, it requires you to include at least one of the following tags in the question:
[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)/[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)/[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)/[support](/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: It depends on what you're asking about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would normally choose [support](/questions/tagged/support).

> This tag is used to request help with the use of one of the Stack Exchange sites' features.

Which site to ask on is definitely help with one of the sites.

I guess you could also use [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), if you want to really discuss which site it should be on.

Comment: So I guess maybe it doesn't really matter, if I could say? I feel like I'd go more easily with [meta-tag:discussion] though … because [meta-tag:support] is about SE sites' features. Thanks for your answer!