# Tagging [site-recommendation] questions asking to recommend sites to ask about stuff related to computers

Tags: support, tags, meta

There are more than 2k questions tagged [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation). Most of these questions are related to stuff that one way or another, is related to computers in any of their form (personal, server, handheld, etc.).

The answer to [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691) has become huge because we have a large number of sites related to computers.

We have tags like [android](/questions/tagged/android), [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app), [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), [google](/questions/tagged/google), among others, but these tags are for questions about using Stack Exchange or the sites, not about the questions about Android, iOS apps, iPhone, Google, etc.

Could we have tags for [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) that help to filter, i.e. site recommendation questions to ask about application software, operative systems, artificial intelligence, networking ([VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), protocols, etc.), privacy / security?

I think that we could have some tags that work like the site categories in https://stackexchange.com/sites (Technology, Culture & recreation, Life & arts, Science, Professional, Business) but as subcategories of the technology category because this category has 77 sites. The other categories have very few sites, so it's possible that fewer questions are asked to recommend a site where the answer belongs to those categories.

#### What about having tags for site recommendations based on the audience?

In the past, there have been discussions about the level of audience, i.e., [Different sites for different levels of audience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225356/289691). There are a few sites like [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) whose audience is "finance professionals and academics", not allowing questions to be too introductory for professional and academic settings. Still, other sites are happy to get any questions of any level.

I think many questions asking for site recommendations are from people looking for help to solve a problem, not to post a high-quality question to build a knowledge library. A tag for a site recommendation might be about the different types of approaches to Q&A that there are across the Technology / Computer-related sites.

---

I.E. In 2014, it was created [If I get stuck on a Codingbat exercise, which Stack Exchange forum would be appropriate for getting assistance so I can understand and move on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214856/289691). This question has [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) + [students](/questions/tagged/students).

In April, I added [students](/questions/tagged/students) to [Where can students ask for professional volunteer assistance?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213457/289691), which already had [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

---

###### Tags that might be used in questions tagged [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)

The numbers in parenthesis next to a tag are the questions having this tag together with [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

| Security Concerns? | Out of Curiosity? Bug? Feature Request? | Asking Questions? | Site? | Ambigous? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [security](/questions/tagged/security) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security+site-recommendation) (6) | [design](/questions/tagged/design) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design+site-recommendation) (3) | [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question+site-recommendation) 25 | [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow+site-recommendation) (40), [serverfault](/questions/tagged/serverfault) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serverfault+site-recommendation) (7), [superuser](/questions/tagged/superuser) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superuser+site-recommendation) (10) | [site-proposal](/questions/tagged/site-proposal) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-proposal+site-recommendation) (12) |
| [privacy](/questions/tagged/privacy) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy+site-recommendation) (1) | [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm+site-recommendation) (3) | [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions+site-recommendation) (51) | [mathoverflow](/questions/tagged/mathoverflow) | [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope+site-recommendation) (105) |
| [login](/questions/tagged/login) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login+site-recommendation) (3) | [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation+site-recommendation) (1) | [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions+site-recommendation) (107) | [ask-different](/questions/tagged/ask-different) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ask-different+site-recommendation) (1) |  |
| [subdomains](/questions/tagged/subdomains) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subdomains+site-recommendation) (1) | [optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization+site-recommendation) (1) |  | [computer-science-se](/questions/tagged/computer-science-se) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science-se+site-recommendation) (4), [software-engineering-se](/questions/tagged/software-engineering-se) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering-se+site-recommendation) (6) |  |
| [exploit](/questions/tagged/exploit) alias of [security](/questions/tagged/security) |  |  | [wordpress-se](/questions/tagged/wordpress-se) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-se+site-recommendation) (3) , [math-se](/questions/tagged/math-se) |  |
|  |  |  | [area-51](/questions/tagged/area-51) [*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area-51+site-recommendation) (26) |  |

#### Notes

1. This is not about mandatory tags, so this is not a duplicate of [What's the best tag to accompany the site-recommendation tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168121/289691)
2. This is not about modifying the site categories at https://stackexchange.com/sites, so this is not a duplicate of [Can we reorganize the categories?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305310/289691)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it will do much good.

While Meta is indeed the place to ask for site recommendation, and it's important part, I don't think it justifies its own set of tags.

Searching for specific topic is easy enough using the ordinary search, e.g. [site recommendation questions about android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsite-recommendation%5D+android+is%3Aq).

Comment: Probably, the tags should be for something less obvious, like the **audience**: programmers, end-users, administrators, and parents. Parents might be similar to admins, but parental controls have very different challenges than admins of a business setting or a home with no children.